# Automatically draft WordPress Posts older than 30 days using CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a WordPress site with 1000s of posts. I'd like to set all posts older than 30 days to `draft` automatically when it reaches the specified date.

Been staring myself blind at the following code - triggering the CRON manually has now effect:

```
<?php
/**
 * Function that will draft specific posts on specific conditions
 *
 * @param \WP_Post $_post
 */
function tgs_maybe_draft_the_post( $_post ) {
    

    $publish_date = get_the_date( 'd M Y', $_post->ID);

    // Bail if no publish date set for some reason.
    if ( ! $publish_date ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Set status to draft if older than 30 days.
    if (strtotime($publish_date) < strtotime('-30 days')) {
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'          => $_post->ID,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ) );
    }
}

/**
 * Register cron event on init action
 */
function tgs_cron_schedule_draft_posts() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'tgs_draft_posts' );
    if ( $timestamp == false ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'tgs_draft_posts' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'tgs_cron_schedule_draft_posts' );

/**
 * Handle deletion of posts periodically.
 * - Loop through the posts and call the tgs_maybe_draft_the_post function.
 */
function tgs_draft_posts_handler() {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
    ) );
    foreach ( $posts as $_post ) {
        tgs_maybe_draft_the_post( $_post );
    }
}
add_action( 'tgs_draft_posts', 'tgs_draft_posts_handler' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can troubleshoot your logic (change status to draft) by running that logic directly during a page view rather than from cron.  Try using the wp_footer action, something like this.

   ```php
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'tgs_draft_posts_handler')
   ```

   You can then include `print_r();` debugging code and it will show up on your rendered page: ugly but useful. You could do `print_r('about to do get_posts');` for example.
2. You can search for posts with [date criteria](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters). That way you don't need a separate check for the posts' age. With thousands of posts this is a significant time saver.

   ```php
       $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
               'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
               'before' => '30 days ago'
            )
          ),
    ) );
   ```
3. Once your basic logic works, you can get it working under cron.

And, turn on the [WordPress debugging stuff](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/). It helps a lot.

When it all works, don't forget to remove the print_r() statements (duh, obviously).

Comment: Noice! Thanks! Good to have an external pair of eyes look into alternatives.